# Total noob-can't run gradle tasks

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, ide, build.gradle

i'm trying to use Eclipse IDE to do an assignment but i can't run gradle tasks...
it says "no actions available"...i'm adding a picture for clarity.[image]

i'll appreciate any help!

p.s. the project is built for java 8, i seem to have java 13... i also have java 8 on my pc but when i type "java -version" in cmd it says 13

**UPDATE: I switched the jre version to 1.8 in Eclipse and now there's 1 error left (see picture below)**
[HERE IS THE LAST ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0jDN.png)

Comment: Gradle 4.4 is pretty ancient at this point, and I don't know if Eclipse still supports it. Any reason not to go for the newest release?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
there was a problem in the file itself, so i switched to intelliJ Idea.

i opened a new gradle project, created a new Java class at the appropriate place and copied the code to there :)

IntelliJ automatically chose an up to date version of gradle.